# How do I prevent Hibernate hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto errors when using a shared dev DB on multiple branches?

Tags: database, hibernate, version-control

Our Java/Spring/Hibernate project uses Feature Branches, and a shared DEV database.  We have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to `create` on the branch I'm on and another branch has it set to `update`.  However, my the DB credentials do not allow schema changes, so I get a host of errors when I start up the application.  We have had problems in the past with people blasting the DEV DB away when they had permissions to change the schema.

1. What is the best setting for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` on a shared dev DB with differing feature branches?
2. How do we prevent branch differences causing problems when DB changes are made in the branches?

I'm having trouble thinking of a good solution to #2.  I know that going to [Trunk-Based-Development](http://paulhammant.com/2013/04/05/what-is-trunk-based-development) would solve this, but that's outside of my control for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told that one option is to set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `validate`.  This will prevent aggressive changes to the DB, while still notifying us of errors when the DB doesn't match the entity annotations.